# A/B Test Send Log

Tags: unit-test, email, email-studio, issue

what is the steps to implement a send log for A/B test send? I have not found anything on the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While configuring A/B test under Send Management>Send Options>Expand it and custom settings you need to select the checkbox for Enable send logging to a data extension.

Check this too While configuring A/B test did you choose the option to enable send log for that A/B test?

Check it and let me know.

Thanks.